# Does Genetic Code Breeding increase the stats of my companion in any way?

Tags: warframe

The Genetic Code Temple [wiki](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Genetic_Code_Template#Stored_Information) says that each template stores:

| Kubrows | Kavats |
| --- | --- |
| Coat Colors (Primary, Secondary, Tertiary) | Coat Colors (Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, Accents) |
| Coat Pattern (Patchy, Hound, Lotus etc.) | Coat Pattern (Hyacinth, Vasca) |
| Eye Color | Eye Color |
| Breed (Sahasa, Raksa, Huras, Sunika, or Chesa) | Breed (Smeeta, Adarza, or Vasca) |
| Build (Skinny, Athletic, Bulky) | Head Type/Tail Type |

However, each breed has different armor, health, shield, polarity etc. values. Does breeding via genetic codes effect this? Can I breed a pet that has the max value of each, or is that specific to the breed that the pet comes out as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base stats are tied to the Breed of your Beast Companion. So if your breeding results in a Huras Kubrow then it will have the stats of a Huras Kubrow.  For most pets this means you'll need to rely on the Mods you equip to improve their stats.  On the bright side, Kubrows can equip the [Kavasa Prime Kubrow Collar](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Kavasa_Prime_Kubrow_Collar) for a small stat boost.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I have done some research and I couldn't find anything saying one way or the other, but I thought that might be the case